# Xorg thinks touchpad is exact pointing device

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, input

I finally got Xorg working with LXDE, but I have one tiny problem: Xorg thinks my touchpad is an exact pointing device, such as a touchscreen. That is, coordinates on the touchpad are directly related to coordinates on the screen. In addition, trying to use the mouse as a touchpad results in clicking and dragging as one would expect on a touchscreen. How do I fix that? `Xorg -configure` complains about no devices and gives up (as I have in finding a solution for this), even though the server reacts to input.